# Importing General formatted cells from Excel files via C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, import, datatable

I currently use:

- Visual Studio 2015 Update 3
- Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013
- .Net Framework 4.5.1
- Windows 7 64bit

I'm reading an Excel worksheet into a DataTable using the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

string filename = "C:\\Users\\myusername\\Documents\\MyFile.xlsx";

DataTable dt = null;

try
{
    string ExcelName = filename.Split(("\\").ToCharArray()[0])[filename.Split(("\\").ToCharArray()[0]).Length - 1].Split('.')[0];

    string ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filename + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\";";

    string SheetName = CommonFunctions.GetExcelSheetNames(ConnectionString)[0];

    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [" + SheetName + "]");

        conn.Open();

        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
        {
            using (OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (rdr.HasRows)
                {
                    dt = new DataTable();

                    dt.TableName = ExcelName;

                    for (int i = 0; i < rdr.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(rdr.GetName(i), typeof(string)));

                    }

                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

                        for (int i = 0; i < rdr.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            dr[i] = rdr[i].ToString();

                        }

                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

                    }

                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        string s = row[0].ToString();

                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace, ex.Message, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

}
```

Example Excel worksheet data is as follows, provided in CSV format for easy opening in Excel:

```
"store_number", "stock_code", "desired_quantity"
"64004", "BI_KRA_SEL_350065", "1"
"64004", "BI_KRA_SEL_500080", "1"
"86208", "BI_KRA_SEL_350065", "1"
"86208", "BI_KRA_SEL_500080", "1"
"64019", "BI_KRA_SEL_350065", "1"
"64019", "BI_KRA_SEL_500080", "1"
"85858", "BI_KRA_SEL_350065", "1"
"85858", "BI_KRA_SEL_500080", "1"
"72122", "BI_KRA_SEL_350065", "1"
"72122", "BI_KRA_SEL_500080", "1"
"68427", "BI_KRA_SEL_350065", "1"
"68427", "BI_KRA_SEL_500080", "1"
"79031", "BI_KRA_SEL_350065", "1"
"79031", "BI_KRA_SEL_500080", "1"
"67662", "BI_KRA_SEL_350065", "1"
"67662", "BI_KRA_SEL_500080", "1"
"92246", "BI_KRA_SEL_350065", "1"
"92246", "BI_KRA_SEL_500080", "1"
"85432", "BI_KRA_SEL_350065", "1"
"85432", "BI_KRA_SEL_500080", "1"
"87188", "BI_KRA_SEL_350065", "1"
"87188", "BI_KRA_SEL_500080", "1"
"91021", "BI_KRA_SEL_350065", "1"
"91021", "BI_KRA_SEL_500080", "1"
"79022", "BI_KRA_SEL_350065", "1"
"79022", "BI_KRA_SEL_500080", "1"
"86369", "BI_KRA_SEL_350065", "1"
"86369", "BI_KRA_SEL_500080", "1"
"67670", "BI_KRA_SEL_350065", "1"
"67670", "BI_KRA_SEL_500080", "1"
"92605", "BI_KRA_SEL_350065", "1"
"92605", "BI_KRA_SEL_500080", "1"
"92609", "BI_KRA_SEL_350065", "1"
"92609", "BI_KRA_SEL_500080", "1"
"92610", "BI_KRA_SEL_350065", "1"
"92610", "BI_KRA_SEL_500080", "1"
"92611", "BI_KRA_SEL_350065", "1"
"92611", "BI_KRA_SEL_500080", "1"
"92612", "BI_KRA_SEL_350065", "1"
"92612", "BI_KRA_SEL_500080", "1"
"92613", "BI_KRA_SEL_350065", "1"
"92613", "BI_KRA_SEL_500080", "1"
"92614", "BI_KRA_SEL_350065", "1"
"92614", "BI_KRA_SEL_500080", "1"
"92615", "BI_KRA_SEL_350065", "1"
"92615", "BI_KRA_SEL_500080", "1"
"92616", "BI_KRA_SEL_350065", "1"
"92616", "BI_KRA_SEL_500080", "1"
"w090", "BI_KRA_SEL_350065", "1"
"w090", "BI_KRA_SEL_500080", "1"
"C908", "BI_KRA_SEL_350065", "1"
"C908", "BI_KRA_SEL_500080", "1"
"w0901", "BI_KRA_SEL_350065", "1"
"w0901", "BI_KRA_SEL_500080", "1"
"G202", "BI_KRA_SEL_350065", "1"
"G202", "BI_KRA_SEL_500080", "1"
```

The issue is when the first column contains letters and/or spaces. These cells appear blank in the resulting DataTable (dt) i.e. from "w090" to "G202".

I have found that this happens when the cells are formatted as 'General'. However, changing the formatting of those cells to 'Text' seems to fix the problem.

The only problem I have now is that I can't rely on my customer to provide files that have the cells set to 'Text' formatting.

Does anybody know a fix for this, or possibly a way to clone the Excel file with 'Text' formatting?

Maybe somebody knows a smarter way to import Excel files into DataTables/DataSets.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure why `string filename = "C:\Users\myusername\Documents\MyFile.xlsx";` should work. Does it not must be `string filename = @"C:\Users\myusername\Documents\MyFile.xlsx";` or `string filename = "C:\\Users\\myusername\\Documents\\MyFile.xlsx";`? Or ist there some gereral setting to have all string literals as verbatim string literals?

Comment: @Axel Richter Thanks for this. I have corrected the string. Note: I could have optionally prefixed the string with an @ symbol.

Comment: Hambone's answer prompted me to replace `adapter.fill` with a `DataReader` to give a greater control over debugging. At the current point of investigation, the data is found to be going missing at the point of or before the `rdr.Read()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good reliable solution using **Interop** services.

**Add reference:** `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` version 12.0.0.0, which is available via Nuget.

**Note:** Be sure to pass the full path as the filename parameter.

```
public static DataTable LoadExcelFile(string fileName, string worksheetName, int headerRowNumber, int firstDataRowNumber)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook ExcelWorkbook = ExcelApplication.Workbooks.Open(fileName, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ExcelWorksheet = null;

    string WorksheetName = worksheetName;

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(worksheetName))
    {
        WorksheetName = ExcelWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name;

    }

    ExcelWorksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)ExcelWorkbook.Worksheets[WorksheetName];

    dt.TableName = WorksheetName;

    // Add the columns

    Dictionary<string, int> Columns = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < ExcelWorksheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        string ColumnHeading = Convert.ToString(((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)ExcelWorksheet.Cells[headerRowNumber, i + 1]).Value2);

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ColumnHeading) && !dt.Columns.Contains(ColumnHeading))
        {
            Columns.Add(ColumnHeading, i + 1);

            dt.Columns.Add(ColumnHeading);

        }

    }

    // Add the rows

    for (int i = 0; i < ExcelWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - firstDataRowNumber + 1; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            int ColumnCount = 0;

            DataRow Row = dt.NewRow();

            bool RowHasContent = false;

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in Columns)
            {
                string CellContent = Convert.ToString(((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)ExcelWorksheet.Cells[i + firstDataRowNumber, kvp.Value]).Value2);

                Row[ColumnCount] = CellContent;

                ColumnCount++;

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CellContent))
                {
                    RowHasContent = true;

                }

            }

            if (RowHasContent)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(Row); ;

            }

        }
        catch
        {

        }

    }

    // Clean up

    try { ExcelWorksheet = null; } catch { }

    try { ExcelWorkbook.Close(); } catch { }

    try { ExcelWorkbook = null; } catch { }

    try { ExcelApplication = null; } catch { }

    return dt;
}
```

**Why use Interop services?**

Interop services gets around the Type guessing and formatting bugs experienced when using solutions based on the `Jet` or `Ace` database engines.

Examples of buggy solutions are as follows:

- ExcelDataReader
- LinqToExcel
- OleDb

If you currently use one of the solutions above then it is worth testing for bugs, and please post successful solutions to this page.

**Pleasant surprises**

Using the Interop solution, I was expecting an issue when a file was open in Excel already with the same name as the one open in the program, but I experienced no such problem during testing.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `Excel` as a database, each field (column) must have its exact data type. The `Excel` database drivers are guessing this type from the first values. In your case those first values are numeric in first column. So the database guesses numeric data type there. So the later occuring strings does not fit into that type.

The database driver has a parameter `IMEX` which leads to treating **all** data as text. See https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/treating-data-as-text/.

So try

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filename + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;IMEX=1\";";
```

or

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filename + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1\";";
```

Comment: This sounds like the perfect logical solution, but even with IMEX = 1, the cells are still treated as numeric. I replaced the line, `string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filename + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0; IMEX=1\";";` and increment through using a foreach like so, `foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        string s = row[0].ToString();

                    }`, but the last few cells are still coming through blank.

Comment: I have no experience with `C# .NET`. But can you try the complete connection string including parameter `HDR`: `string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filename + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0; HDR=NO; IMEX=1\";";`? If this also not works, then I cannot help.

Comment: Hm, displaying in https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/treating-data-as-text/ seems to be misleading. There are not spaces between semicolon and next property in `Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: At first I tried, `string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filename + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1\";";` Initially, I thought this had worked, but this was due to `HDR=NO`, making the first cell a text value. Changing the value to `HDR=YES` meant the first row was used as the header again (this verifies that the HDR switch at least works), but the last few cells are still coming through blank. I don't know why, but the IMEX switch does not seem to work, or at least we're using it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little more work than just using `adapter.Fill()`, but if you want to have more control over the datatypes you can declare them up front and then fill the DataTable one row at a time.  Because it's Excel and Excel will happily mix and match datatypes within a column, I think it's nearly impossible for OleDb to determine the correct datatypes up front.

Here is an example of how you can explicitly declare the datatypes and then insert them into the datatable manually:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

object[] fields = new object[reader.FieldCount];
for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(reader.GetName(i)));

dt.Columns[0].DataType = typeof(string);
dt.Columns[1].DataType = typeof(string);
dt.Columns[2].DataType = typeof(int);

while (reader.Read())
{
    reader.GetValues(fields);
    dt.Rows.Add(fields);
}

reader.Close();
```

-- EDIT 1/3/2017 --

Here is a solution using POCOs that I believe will work:

If your POCO looks like this:

```
public class Stock
{
    public string StoreNumber { get; set; }
    public string StockCode { get; set; }
    public double DesiredQuantity { get; set; }
}
```

This code should read the data from Excel and put it into a list of domain objects:

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
conn.Open();

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

List<Stock> stockData = new List<Stock>();

while (reader.Read())
{
    stockData.Add(new Stock()
    {
        StoreNumber = reader.GetValue(0).ToString(),
        StockCode = reader.GetValue(1).ToString(),
        DesiredQuantity = reader.GetDouble(2)
    });
}

reader.Close();
```

I think a `.GetString(x)` might throw an error due to the problem you highlighted, but by using `.GetValue(x).ToString()`, you can brute force the datatypes, knowing they should all be strings.

From here, I think using the `List<Stock>` will be a joy to work with, compared to the datatable.  The best part is you exert total control over the data.

Comment: This was interesting to experiment with. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work, but I do appreciate the extra control this solution provides. Thanks to this answer, I have found that the datatype within the reader (reader.MetaData.[0].columnBinding.ExpectedType) is a System.Double, so I have been experimenting with the query. However, I have discovered that CAST and CONVERT is not supported by the OleDb class. I also found hint to alter a value named 'TypeGuessRows' in the registry to 0, but that didn't help either.

Comment: I guess I should have asked...  are you married to the datatable?  What are you doing with this once you read the data?  I am partial to POCOs over datatables, but even I admit there is a time and place for them.  If you know the content ahead of time (which it appears you do), you can exert a lot more control with objects.

Comment: Sounds great to me and I'd welcome a POCO based solution to try. The reason I used DataTables is because they are generic and are easy to pass as a DataSource to a GridView control in a WinForms app. I don't mind using dedicated classes at all, especially if it solves my problem and means I stop losing data.

Comment: Excellent!  I put an example that uses POCOs, and I actually tested it this time...  for what it's worth, it worked for me on the sample data you provided.

Comment: Still no joy. The root problem seems to be at some point before the data is passed to the reader. I wonder if the reason it worked for you was because the cells were formatted to 'text' instead of 'general'. I really appreciate your help in this. I feel like we're so close to the solution we can almost touch it. I also agree with you about POCOs. They are quite elegant, and much much nicer to debug than DataTables.

Comment: That stinks...  it has to be something with the spreadsheet.  Do you have Excel installed on the machine where this runs?  If so, you can just use interop to read the spreadsheet.  If you care to, upload the spreadsheet and I can take a look.  It's a matter of pride at this point.

Comment: I would do in a flash. Embarrassingly, I don't actually know how to upload an Excel file to Stackoverflow.com. It's the reason I copied and pasted it.

Comment: You can use Skydrive, OneDrive (Microsoft), Google Docs, Drop Box...  Once you put them in one of those places, you can just post a link for download.  Did the Linq to Excel work?

Comment: I had the same problems with ExcelDataReader and LinqToExcel, since they rely on Jet and Ace database engines, however testing with Interop services was successful. The only drawback is that Office needs to be installed on the machine compiling the code. It may also need to be installed on the user's machine too. I don't know this yet.

Comment: Yes, with interop it will.  There are third party drivers that can read an Excel file without interop, though.  I've heard good things about EPPlus but don't know much about it -- I don't know if it needs Excel or not.  From personal experience, I can tell you I used a tool called "Excel Data Reader" (very generic name), which works very well.  There are plenty of others -- check those out and see which one makes sense.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did test ExcelDataReader and it exhibits the same bug due to being an implimentation of the Ace database engine. The bug appears to be in both Ace and Jet database engines, which is why all the methods I've tried so far that use them have failed. I did find Interop on Nuget though, which looks like I can use it without having Office installed. I'll test it over the weekend since I use Open Office at home.